# Error while trying to install llvmlite on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python

I am trying to install llvmlite on my ssystem in order to install numba. I have got an error when I did `python setup.py build`, the first error that appear is
`assembly.cpp:3:35: fatal error: llvm/AsmParser/Parser.h: No such file or directory
 #include "llvm/AsmParser/Parser.h"`

Could someone give me a hint what went wrong?

The full error message is here - http://dpaste.com/2G7BVNY

And `dpkg --get-selections|grep llvm` results in

```
libllvm3.3:amd64                install
libllvm3.4:amd64                install
libllvm3.4:i386                 install
libllvm3.5:amd64                install
llvm                        install
llvm-3.3                    install
llvm-3.3-dev                    install
llvm-3.3-runtime                install
llvm-3.4                    install
llvm-3.4-dev                    install
llvm-3.4-runtime                install
llvm-3.5                    install
llvm-3.5-dev                    install
llvm-3.5-runtime                install
llvm-runtime                    install
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to install it in Python 3.4 using `llvm-3.5` (as required in the README.py) in Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. I had to make a symbolic link in `/usr/bin` to `llvm-config`.

```
sudo ln -s llvm-config-3.5 llvm-config
```

I couldn't make it work with `LLVM_CONFIG` enviroment variable.

I also had to install `libedit-dev` as the README.md suggests.

Then `python3 setup.py install` worked flawlessly.